# New folders are created in root instead of currently selected folder

Tags: snow-leopard, mac, folders

When I click on a folder and choose File->New Folder the folder is created in the root directory of my current view instead of the currently selected (highlighted) folder.

How do I make it so when I create a new folder it will create the folder inside of the current highlighted directory?

Answer (score 5):

You can't.  Finder creates new folders in the folder currently being displayed, not the folder you've highlighted.  First you have to display the folder you want the new one in - double click it, then create the new one.

Comment: oh, i thought you could because someone told me theirs creates the folder in the highlighted folder.

Comment: Jeez, this IS the sh**iest OS on the planet :(

Answer (score 1):

Open the folder you want to create the new folder in first (double-click). Then choose File->New Folder or Shift-Cmd-N.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to do that in Finder (as of macOS 12 Monterey, 2021), but you can create a custom Automator action instead. This will provide a right click menu item, as well as a keyboard shortcut, to create a folder under the selected folder in Finder.

See the detailed steps at this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169636/how-can-i-create-a-folder-in-the-current-directory-in-list-view/448774#448774).

Comment: ...or you can just use Column view.